# Xamarin Forms buttons stop receiving mouse clicks after clicking on SkiaSharp CanvasView on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, skiasharp

I use SkiaSharp canvas to draw the main game screen, and then there are various Xamarin.Forms Buttons around the UI. This all works fine on when used directly on iPhone or iPad using a finger. However, when I connect a mouse (e.g., through a MacBook or otherwise), the buttons start working with about 10% chance after mouse-clicking on the SkiaSharp canvas (and not receiving the mouse click events with 90% chance). The SkiaSharp canvas itself works just fine.

If I bring up the iOS app launch menu from the bottom (which probably somehow temporarily exists the mouse navigation on the app), the buttons start working again with the mouse. But if I click the SkiaSharp canvas again with the mouse, the buttons have a high chance of becoming disabled again. If I change to using a finger, all works fine (even if the mouse clicks were not being registered immediately before). However, mouse clicks are not being registered even after touching with a finger, so finger-touching does not reset the issue with the mouse (but bringing up the menu from the bottom does).

We found this bug by testing the iOS game on MacBook Pro (the iOS apps recently came available on the App Store) but the same issue persists also directly with an iPad / mouse combination. It seems to be some sort of an issue between using a mouse (on iPad or on MacBook Pro), SkiaSharp canvas and Xamarin.Forms buttons.

Does anyone know what the root cause of the problem is and what is the workaround?

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Hi, there are several tens of thousands of lines of code, but the bit that is probably relevant can be found at https://github.com/hyvanmielenpelit/GnollHack/blob/master/win/win32/winclisrv/GnollHackClient/GnollHackClient/Pages/Game/GamePage.xaml.cs  as well as the corresponding XAML page. If you want to test the issue, you can download the game using Apple's TestFlight beta test service with the link https://testflight.apple.com/join/FI7LuppZ  If you connect a mouse to an iOS device or download the game to a Mac via App Store and try to use it with a mouse, you should experience the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer as such, but some more information about reproducing the issue: A simpler repro case may be this small project: https://github.com/jrc14/TraceMatching/   .
Don't worry too much about what it's doing, but note that you're mean to click in the grey Skia canvas in the middle to create 'targets' - and that after you've done that, mouse-clicks are getting lost.
If you run it on a Mac, you'll see that, though the clicks get lost after you've clicked on the Skia canvas, they will start being received again if you click on something else (another app, or the Mac background).
(further edit) - after some noodling around I did find a workaround.  If, once you've finished processing the touch action on the SKCanvasView, you reset its EnableTouchEvents property (i.e. set it to false, then back to true again), it seems that the clicks don't get lost any more,